# Remote Web Server creates new File instead of new Folder

Tags: directory, webserver

I've been using HostGator (HG) as a web hosting service since 2014 and haven't had too many issues until about a week ago.Now, when I try to create a remote folder a new file gets created instead. I've encountered the same issue with Sublime Text, VS Code and FileZilla. I've been using Sublime and FileZilla for years - using the same process - without any problems until a week or so ago.

So far, HG's  Tech Support has been unable to find a solution. Even more unfortunately, I don't think they're looking at the real problem. I made the mistake of mentioning that I had received errors in Sublime relating to the SFTP extension that I use to connect and create content and they continue to focus on that aspect - even tho I've had the same problem with 2 other programs that use different methods but encounter the same problem: instead of creating a new folder, a new file gets created. If I then connect directly to the server, I can delete that file and then try to recreate the folder, which usually works.

It seems to me that this problem isn't all that uncommon, but so far Google hasn't provided any helpful results. My searches so far have centered around "remote linux server creates new file instead of new folder" because that's essentially the problem. Has anyone else ever had this problem? If so, how can I explain it to HG's tech support in a way that will allow them to resolve it?

I can't recall the OS on the remote server in question, but I'm going to look into it and post an update when I find out, since that could be critical to resolving this.

Comment: Can you describe your workflow for doing this? You seem to have a custom setup, and it isn't really clear which protocols and/or software are involved here.

Comment: @Haxiel It's pretty standard. As I'm working on different sites, I need to create new folders fairly frequently. In Sublime Text, for instance, the left side of the editor shows local files, and when I need to create a new folder, I right-click on a local folder and create a new folder inside of it, Then, I also create a new file and save it inside of the new folder and when I save the file, Sublime usually creates both the folder and file on the remote server.  1/2

Comment: That's the same way I've been doing it for years, but for some reason just recently, instead of creating a new folder remotely, a new file gets created instead. Let me know if any additional clarity would be helpful. Thanks! ¦-þ 2/2

Comment: I looked into this a bit more, and as I understand it, Sublime Text uses plugins to make this happen. I don't have a clear-cut solution for you, but I can give you some pointers to investigate further. First, identify the specific protocol that you're using. FTP, FTPS and SFTP are different protocols, so the debugging steps will vary. Once you have that, use a different client program to recreate the problem. If it occurs again, you can focus on investigating the server. If it doesn't happen, you can focus on the plugin you use with Sublime Text.

Comment: @Haxiel Thanks for your continued interest in this issue: Truly appreciated! I'm using SFTP with the Sublime plugin. I don't think it's the source of the problem, however, because I've run into the same issue with both VS Code and FileZilla (I mentioned this in my OP, but I may not have been clear enough). I'll probably contact the plugin developer to see if he has any thoughts, but right now it appears as though I'll either have to learn how to deal with it or look for a different provider. I'll leave this open for now just to see if anyone has any additional insight.